# Spring4 doesn't load injected bean mongoTemplate successfully

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc, mongotemplate

I got a project to use spring framework and mongodb, but now I got a problem to load mongoTemplate successfully.

here is my pom.xml:

```
<properties>
...
<org.springframework.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
<jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
<spring.mongodb.version>1.5.1.RELEASE</spring.mongodb.version>
<mongo.java.driver>2.9.3</mongo.java.driver>
...
</properties>

<!-- mongo -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>${mongo.java.driver}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.mongodb.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

here is spring-mongo-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.5.xsd">

<!-- Default bean name is 'mongo' -->
<mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="27017">
    <!-- OPTIONAL: configure <mongo:options /> -->
</mongo:mongo>

<mongo:db-factory dbname="test" mongo-ref="mongo"/>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

After configuration done, I wrote a junit testcase to test it upfront, however it always fails. here is the testcase,

```
public class MongoRepositoryTest extends TestCase {
@Autowired
private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

/**
 * setup
 */
@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    try {
        this.context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:/WEB_INF/spring-mongo-config.xml");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }       
}

public void testMongoConfig(){
    System.out.println(GitGerritLogsLegacyRepositoryImpl.class);
    System.out.println(context.getBeanDefinitionNames().length + "===");
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = (MongoTemplate) context.getBean("mongoTemplate");
}
}
```

The error message goes like below,

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'mongoTemplate' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:641)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1159)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:282)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
at test.java.com.datahub.repository.MongoRepositoryTest.testMongoConfig(MongoRepositoryTest.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:154)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
```

It seems **MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = (MongoTemplate) context.getBean("mongoTemplate");** always runs into error. Am I wrong somewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: If need more information, leave the comments, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolve it as stupid mistake by myself, dam.... ;-)

Just change the build path, change main.java.webapp and main.java.resources as source, and make sure the build of src should exclude above two sources.

```
Project (right click) -> Java Build Path -> add folder 
Or
Go to webapp and resource folder and right click to set as source.
```

Then I update my maven project, in the end build it and pass. Yes!!!

Comment: Another thing, most of the error contains *No bean named 'xxx' is defined* probably are caused by build environment issue.